# How to auto run script upon driver reboot?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, files, drivers

I am trying to set an auto run on my shell script (named driver_check.sh) which will trigger upon rebooting the driver.

Basically, my script is as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start script"
    now=$(date +"%T")
    LOGFILE_HOME=/var/opt/mydriver/log/startupFail.log
echo "======== LOG EVENT CHECKING ========" >> $LOGFILE_HOME
echo "DATE: $(date +%Y-%m-%d ) $now" >> $LOGFILE_HOME
echo "------------------" >> $LOGFILE_HOME
for loop in {1..3}
do
        echo $loop
        echo "Loop $loop" >> $LOGFILE_HOME
        now=$(date +"%T")
        echo "Current time : $now"

        if grep -iq success /var/opt/mydriver/log/driver.log
        then 
            echo "ok"
            break

        else
            if [ $loop = 3 ]
            then 
                    #send email
                    mail -s "Fail to restart/reboot" myemail@domain.com

                    echo "Fail"
                    echo "Fail" >> $LOGFILE_HOME
                    echo "An email has sent>> $LOGFILE_HOME
            fi  
        fi  


        ((loop ++));
        sleep 3


    done
```

I have tried adding this line at the beginning of the script

```
chmod 755 driver_check.sh
```

I have also moved the file to /etc/init.d
The script still do not auto run when I restart the driver. What else should I do to make it works?
Really appreciates any advice you guys can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Puting the script in /etc/init.d will not be enough to execute it at reboot. 
Depending of your linux distribution, you should check for runlevel and how to run a script at startup (either init.d, systemd, rc.d ....)

On redhat/CentOS < 7, you have `chkconfig`[1] to manage such things, adding the correct header to you script, it will automagically creates the correct link so that script will be launch at correct runlevel.

[1] on redhat 7 and CentOS 7 this tool don't manage systemd service

Comment: My linus distrbution is SUSELinux 3.0.76 (I think?).
What do you mean by check for runlevel? Is it creating symbolic link? 
How do I know which run level? 
This code chkconfig, how do I use it? I tried typing into the command line but all I see is on/off variables that I do not understand.
Really appreciates your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use udev to execute command on hardware change. I can't say more how to use it but it will certenly help you.